# How to print out which groups the current process belongs to on Linux?

Tags: c, linux

How can I get a list of groups that the currently running process is subscribed too?

Comment: programmatically or interactively? Since you tagged it as C I would assume programmatically, but it is worth checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getegid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getegid), [`getgroups(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getgroups)

Answer (score 0):

`groups` give the groups the current process is a member of.
`groups username` is the groups of the username. 
See `man groups`